# Access Object property in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have function written in typescript where i am passing the object and key as an input parameter and in function return i am expecting the object with key value pair:

```
const article = {
    id: 1,
    title: "TypeScript Explained",
    active: true,
    getSlug: () => 'typescript-explained',
};
```

`type Pick<T, U extends keyof T> = { [K in U]: T[K] };`

```
function pick<T,U extends keyof T>(obj:T,key:U):Pick<T,U>{
    return  {[key]: obj[key]}
}
```

```
pick(article,'title')
```

But on calling the function i am getting the error like Type '{ [x: string]: T[U]; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<T, U>'.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please format the question so we can read it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript infers that type of `{[key]: obj[key]}` is `{ [x: string]: T[U]; }`.

Thats why it panics when you try to return it as `Pick<T,U>`

You can either let it infer return type:

```
 function pick<T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: U) {
    return { [key]: obj[key] };
  }
```

then function returns `{ [x: string]: T[U]; }`

or explicitly set type of `{[key]: obj[key]}` with `as`:

```
 function pick<T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: U): Pick<T, U> {
    return { [key]: obj[key] } as Pick<T, U>;
  }
```

then function returns value of type

```
Pick<{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    active: boolean;
    getSlug: () => string;
}, "title">
```

Comment: what about 
`function pick<T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: U): Partial<T> {
  return { [key]: obj[key] } as T;
}` ?

Comment: @VinayakVohra Result type is: ```Partial<{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    active: boolean;
    getSlug: () => string;
}>``` since T is typeof `obj`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be working. Thank you. But when i already defined  key as Union of keys(with keyof operator)  from the object then why its treating it as 'string' rather than a object key.

Comment: @ramahuja Second argument of `pick()` has typeof `"id" | "title" | ... <all keys of first argument as strings>` so typeof key will be `string` since you can pick any of available strings I think